# Palavra que descreva a sensação ruim de não conseguir responder todas as mensagens

Tags: palavra-para-ideia

Me deparei recentemente com o seguinte questionamento em um perfil no Twitter:

> Devia ter um nome pra sensação de desespero gerada por não conseguir responder todas as mensagens do zap.

> Sempre quero responder, aí fico ansioso e quanto mais mensagem acumulada, mais anti social fico e menos eu respondo e me fecho

> Eu real sofro internamente com isso ): perdão`

Existe na língua portuguesa alguma palavra que descreva essa sensação?

Quase como um TOC que te obriga a responder todas, mas não é a sensação do TOC em si, e sim a ansiedade e frustração causadas por não conseguir responder tudo. Ou será que cai tudo na descrição de TOC mesmo?

Comment: Eu não tenho e creio que ninguém neste site tenha capacitação para saber disso, já que aqui é sobre a língua portuguesa. Em relação à palavra, creio seria “ansiedade”, “ânsia”, etc.

Comment: Não concordo, Schilive. victorantunes procura uma palavra ou expressão para descrever algo - não um diagnóstico médico. :)

Comment: @ANevesthinksSEisevil, sim, mas ele perguntou se se encaixaria “TOC”, o que só é sabível através dum médico. Ninguém aqui pode falar se se encaixa ou não em TOC“.

Comment: Na língua portuguesa não há obviamente, pois mensagens no telefone são algo muito recente. Se houver, estará no vocabulário médico, mas ainda assim creio que não existe. Qualquer pessoa com vida dificilmente teria necessidade de expressar esse conceito com mais do que frequência mínima, portanto 'ânsia/ansiedade de responder/corresponder' já bastaria.

Answer (score 3):

No Transtorno Obsessivo-Compulsivo (TOC), o indivíduo apresenta ansiedade extrema que só é alividada quando ele executa uma determinada ação, a compulsão.  Por exemplo, a ansiedade causada pelo pensamento obsessivo de estar com as mãos infectadas e que só é aliviada com a lavagem das mãos, a compulsão.

**O caso descrito no OP preenche *aparentemente* alguns critérios para o diagnóstico de TOC: desespero gerado por não conseguir realizar um determinado ato, i.e. responder todas as mensagens**. Nesses casos o conjunto é chamado de Transtorno Obsessivo-Compulsivo.

**Respondendo então à tua pergunda sobre a sensação de desespero gerada por não conseguir responder a todas as mensagens, eu sugiro simplesmente "ansiedade"**. Essa é a expressão mais adequada para descrever o sentimento.

Para ler mais sobre o assunto siga os links:
[**1**](https://books.google.com.br/books?hl=pt-BR&lr=&id=fLw3AgAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA4&dq=transtorno+obsessivo+compulsivo&ots=T4DcsC-64Y&sig=kOJgNSrtd-8xaXM_brqGKGk9rEc#v=onepage&q=transtorno%20obsessivo%20compulsivo&f=false).
,[**2**](https://saude.abril.com.br/mente-saudavel/toc-nao-e-brincadeira-entenda-como-funciona-o-transtorno/) e [**3**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transtorno_obsessivo-compulsivo)

Comment: É apenas uma opinião, mas acho que não deveríamos nem pensar em escrever sobre algo assim (TOC), já que não somos médicos. Mesmo se alguém for, a opinião médica e a não médica podem se assemelhar para quem as vê. Não estou duvidando da tua capacidade, Centaurus — desculpa se pareceu isso —. É só a minha opinião, claro.

Comment: @bad_coder  Aqui, um médico formado pela Universidade do Estado do Rio de Janeiro há 40 anos, (cópia do diploma a disposição)  atuante em Clínica Geral e Cardiologia.  Não escrevo nem faço afirmações levianas. Escrevo apenas sobre aquilo que conheço bem.

Comment: @user4788.  Solicito ler meu comentário acima.

Comment: @Centaurus — sou user4788 —, eu só quis dizer que este site não tem a garantia de saber quem é médico. Fico feliz em saber que um médico escreveu isso.

Answer (score 1):

> sensação de desespero

Bom, para começar o desespero é o contrário da esperança. Portanto a definição do que isto diz é uma situação sem esperança, o que naturalmente atinje o indivíduo a vários níveis. Alias, são incontáveis as emoções que acompanham o desespero e uma enumeração adequada deve ser circunstanciada. O primeiro passo nestas situações é a análise objectiva da situação que causa o desespero e das reais privações que decorrem para o indivíduo em causa, por forma a compreender se a sensação subjectiva corresponde às circunstâncias objectivas.

> Sempre quero responder, aí fico ansioso e quanto mais mensagem acumulada, mais anti social fico e menos eu respondo e me fecho

A análise deste trecho é mais complicado. Enquanto em termos orgânicos as palavras *"ansiedade"* e *"stress"* são *talvez* adequadas; Devemos também pensar em termos de *"expectativa"*, *"pressão social"*, *"hábito"*, *"vontade"*, *"solicitação"*, *"impulso"* e *"percepção"* (tudo isto são também termos cuja adequação maior ou menor depende do caso).

É óbvio que o *"vício da internet"* seja como viciação ou simplesmente um hábito, é um tendência moderna que tende a afectar um número crescente de pessoas.

> mais anti social fico e menos eu respondo e me fecho

Esta passagem indica, antes de mais, um uso incorrecto da internet.

Podemos aqui facilmente falar de *"imaturidade"* ou *"inexperiência"*, utilizadores experientes de internet recomendam desligar a ligação e fazer outra coisa qualquer assim que sentirmos algum mal estar derivado da utilização...Portanto, não é preciso nenhum transtorno para sentir isto, é uma tendência natural para muitas pessoas quererem responder quando são interpeladas, e sentirem algum mal-estar se não o fizerem. (Mais não seja pelo dilema de precisarem de tomar uma decisão que talvez contrarie a sua primeira reação.)

Mas estamos ainda no campo da [fenomenologia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenomenologia) sem termos dado um passo para o campo ciências médicas. É preciso prudência para distinguir o uso de descrições figurativas que recorrem a terminologia médica para casos aos quais tal não se aplica.

É o último trecho que pode resolver o problema:

> Eu real sofro internamente com isso ): perdão`

Se uma pessoa diz que sofre, tal deve por prudência ser levado a sério. É só mediante o exercício da escuta que se pode formar um juízo sobre o termo mais adequada a cada caso. Uma única palavra não faz uma descrição.

> perdão

Por fim ainda temos mais esta palavra, que se prende com *"má consciência"* ou *"culpa"*. Aqui já estamos no campo da moral em que a pessoa devia ou não devia ter feito. Mas esta *"sensação"* (e sensação não é a palavra mais adequada) é diferente das outras componentes que perfazem a descrição. De modo que a descrição é uma amálgama de diferentes sensações.

(Em bom Português o caso é de fácil solução: Não usem o twitter.)

[*"Cortar o mal pela raiz"*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disfemismo), é [*"Remédio Santo"*](https://www.facebook.com/remediosanto/)...

Comment: kkk não usar o twitter resolve muita coisa! Eu realmente não esperava uma análise tão aprofundada, me esclareceu bastante. Muito obrigado!